# Get the $index of selected option in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCategory" ng-options="category as category.title for category in categories"></select>
```

Obviously, this will not work:

```
<button ng-click="removeCategory($index)">remove</button>
```

How could $index be accessed if not in a repeater?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't need to keep track of the index, simply remove the selectedCategory from the categories model in the removeCategory function:

Your controller might look like this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Riffic/BXHmM/)**:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.model = {
    selectedCategory: {},
    categories: [
        {title: "Cat1"},
        {title: "Cat2"}
    ]
  }
  //init
  $scope.model.selectedCategory = $scope.model.categories[0];

  $scope.removeCategory = function(){
    var ind = $scope.model.categories.indexOf( $scope.model.selectedCategory );
    $scope.model.categories.splice( ind, 1 );
    $scope.model.selectedCategory = $scope.model.categories[0];
  }
}])
```